# Commit message not showing up after commit

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code

I have a little issue with the commit messages not showing up after a commit is done. It only shows if i associated a work item in our TFS.

The output in VS code shows this when i add a associated work item from the TFS, comment and commit:

```
tf checkin -noprompt -collection:https://domain ******** 
/Users/Repos/Main/Frontend/grid.jade -comment: #148 - test commit message -associate:148
Changeset 140 checked in.
```

While this is how a commit looks in the output when i don´t associate a work item:

```
tf checkin -noprompt -collection:https://domain ******** 
/Users/Repos/Main/Frontend/grid.jade
Changeset 141 checked in.
```

The commit comment is gone. If anyone got an fix for this i would appreciate it :-)

Commit comments are quite important to have in relation to a commit, and i don´t want to associate every minor commit to a work item in TFS.

**My specs:**
HW: Mac OSX - 10.12.6
SW: Visual Studio Code - 1.16.1

We use Visual Studio Team Services (TFS)

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue, cannot submit the comment with changeset. Seems there's something wrong with the [Visual Studio Team Services Extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team) or Visual Studio Code itself.

I have submitted a feedback for you, please track it here : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/123402/vscode-comments-cannot-be-submitted-with-changeset.html

For now, as a workaround, you can use the Visual Studio with Team explorer to check in the changes with comment.

Or, directly check in with [`tf checkin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/checkin-command) command:

```
tf checkin -noprompt -comment:"test commit message"
```